# DX10 Skybox Shader

Tags: directx, hlsl, direct3d10

I'm trying to write a skybox shader in DX10 using the following HLSL code:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// world matrix for each rendered object
float4x4 g_mWorld;

// single cubemap texture
Texture2D g_tCubeMap;

// basic mirror texture sampler
SamplerState g_sSamplerMirror
{
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT;
    AddressU = MIRROR;
    AddressV = MIRROR;
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// pre-defined vertex formats for vertex input layouts
struct VS_INPUT
{
    float3 Position     : POSITION;
};

struct PS_INPUT
{
    float4 SPosition    : SV_POSITION;
    float3 UV           : TEXCOORD;
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
PS_INPUT VS_Default( VS_INPUT Input )
{
    PS_INPUT Output = (PS_INPUT)0;

    Output.SPosition = float4(Input.Position,1.0f);
    Output.UV = normalize( mul( Output.SPosition, g_mWorld ) ).xyz;

    return Output;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
float4 PS_Default( PS_INPUT Input ) : SV_TARGET0
{
    return float4( texCUBE( g_sSamplerMirror, Input.UV ) );
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
technique10 TECH_Default
{
    pass
    {
        SetVertexShader( CompileShader( vs_4_0, VS_Default() ) );
        SetPixelShader( CompileShader( ps_4_0, PS_Default() ) );
        SetGeometryShader( 0 );
    }
}
```

Which gives the error "DX-9 style intrinsics are disabled when not in dx9 compatibility mode."  on line 46:

```
return float4( texCUBE( g_sSamplerMirror, Input.UV ) );
```

Is there an alternative to texCUBE? How can I fix this without enabling dx9 compatibility mode?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using [Shader Model 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509657%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) you should be able to create [a `TextureCube` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509700%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and then [call the `Sample` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509695%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: This fixes the problem but gives me this error:
D3D10: ERROR: ID3D10Device::DrawIndexed: Rasterization Unit is enabled (PixelShader is not NULL or Depth/Stencil test is enabled) but position is not provided by the last shader before the Rasterization Unit. [ EXECUTION ERROR #362: DEVICE_DRAW_POSITION_NOT_PRESENT ]
D3D10: ERROR: ID3D10Device::DrawIndexed: A Vertex Shader is always required when drawing, but none is currently bound. [ EXECUTION ERROR #341: DEVICE_DRAW_VERTEX_SHADER_NOT_SET ]

Comment: Ah, D3D10's exceedingly verbose error messages. Unfortunately I don't quite see how those are being generated from just the code you pasted above; it seems like you are both writing a position in your vertex shader *and* setting the shader in the effect -- maybe the vertex shader is being unset accidentally in your C++ code?